# Activate CSS Animation when visible

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am using a CSS animation on my webpage, this animation is in the middle of my page. Its animation starts as soon as I visit the webpage. So the user is not able to see it, I have tried few solutions provided on the internet but none of it seems to work for me.

```css
.pcb-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pcb-text p {
  font-size: 35px;
  animation: typing 2s steps(45), 
             blink-caret 0.85s step-end infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: .12em solid orange;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pcb-text" id="animated_text">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p>Some Text Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I am new to this, so I would really appreciate that if you are giving an answer which includes JS or JQuery, please use a simple method which I can understand**

Comment: There is no error in your code. I even runned it in internet explorer. I would like to suggest you to review console at your website and look for errors. Maybe the problem is not in this code, but some another code in your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the animation in a separate class, and add this class when the element is scrolled into view.

This can be done with jQuery by adding a custom function that detects when the element is in view, and trigger this function every time the user scrolls.

```js
// function to detect if an element is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
};

// listen for scroll event
$(window).scroll(function () {
  // check if element is scrolled into view
  if (isScrolledIntoView($('#animated_text'))) {
    // element is scrolled into view, add animation class
    $('#animated_text').addClass('animation');
  }
});
```

```css
.pcb-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pcb-text p {
  font-size: 35px;
 
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: .12em solid orange;
}

/* move animation to separate class */
.animation p {
  animation: typing 2s steps(45), 
             blink-caret 0.85s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
<div class="pcb-text" id="animated_text">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p>Some Text Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that only work on desktop, but on phone don't, you know why?